# IS it possible to have savefiledialog () in windows console applications

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Diagnostics
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = null;
            using (SaveFileDialog sFile = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                sFile.Filter = "Text (Tab delimited)(*.txt)|*.txt|CSV (Comma separated)(*.csv)|*.csv";
                if (sFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filename = sFile.FileName;
                    WriteRegKey(diagnostic, filename);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:
The type or namespace name 'SaveFileDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I did try adding the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace, but I was not able to.

Comment: What do you mean by you aren't able to add the System.Window.Forms namespace? Did you add it to your references? Did you get an error message?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this would be to have a separate application for the file manipulation based on Windows Forms, and call to that from your console application.

Comment: Of course, you can do. You may just need to add `reference` to `System.Window.Forms`

Comment: no I didnot added it to reference

Comment: Thank u all for ur replies . Will now start to work my way to understand the problem and to fix it .:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly.

Also, you must add the `STAThread` attribute to your application entry point method.

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog sFile = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        sFile.ShowDialog();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But honestly, that's a **terrible** idea. A console application shouldn't have any other UI that the console itself. As the namespace of `SaveFileDialog` suggests, `SaveFileDialog` should be used for `Forms` only.

Comment: I did, at least once, have a need to do this, but I agree in general it's not a great idea. In my particular case I wanted to be able to show an about dialog that told the user what args to pass and how to use it because my users wouldn't otherwise understand how to you a console app. It was important however that the program could be called from the command line to integrate with other programs (in particular PowerPoint) without creating it's own windows.

Comment: It's not that bad an idea.  If I want to write a quick program to do something involving a file and give it to a friend, but don't want to write a whole UI around it, just opening a file picker from a console application is the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @dtanders If the input of the application is a file name, then you could (should IMO) use the command line parameters.

Comment: @ken2k Not everyone can figure that stuff out.  Command line arguments would obviously be even easier to handle from the program than a file dialogue, but command line stuff is scary voodoo magic to some people.  Oh, and then try explaining that any path with spaces has to be surrounded in quotes - consider your audience, basically.

Answer (score 11):

You might find it easier to reverse the problem and have a Windows Forms app with a console. To do this, create a Windows Forms app in Visual Studio. Delete the default form it creates. Open up program.cs and remove the code that tries to create a window and replace it with your console app code.

Now the trick is that you need to manually create the console. You can do it with this helper class:

```
public class ConsoleHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allocates a new console for current process.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

    /// <summary>
    /// Frees the console.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();
}
```

Now at the beginning of your program (before you try and Console.Writeline's) call

```
ConsoleHelper.AllocConsole();
```

And at the very end of your program call

```
ConsoleHelper.FreeConsole();
```

Now you have a console app that can create WinForms dialogs, including the SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms to the project itself, not the source file. Right click the project icon in the **Solution Explorer** toolbox and select "add reference".

Answer (score 1):

You have **not imported** the namespace System.Windows.Forms into your code.

You need to **add reference** to System.Windows.Forms from **'Add Reference' Dialog Box**. Then call the namespace **'using System.Windows.Forms'** (without quotes) and make the object of **SaveFileDialog** Class.