# VSTO Addin Save File Dialog

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a VSTO addin that has a form with a saveFileDialog on it.  I want to pass a specific filename and path to saveFileDialog to set the properties FileName and InitialDirectory.  The problem is the only way I can see to do it is to modify InitializeComponent() and the Form constructor to take parameters filename and path to set those properties.  The problem is that visual studio says not to modify that part of the file and will even delete code added/altered there which happened when I tried that method.

What is the correct method to pass in these variables to set those properties?  Can I use saveFileDialog without a form or is that unnecessary?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    internal string filename;
    internal string path;

    public Form2(string filename, string path)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.path = path;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog2.FileName = filename;
        saveFileDialog2.InitialDirectory = path;

    }
}
```

and using the form:

```
var frm2 = new Form2(filename, path);
DialogResult result = frm2.ShowDialog();
```

I call this in the button click handler for a button I added to a ribbon group.

Would this do it?   Before I was modifying Initialize component to accept parameters, but as you aren't supposed to touch that method, I got rid of my changes and changed it to what I pasted here.

In case I wasn't clear what I'm trying to do is pop up a save file dialog with filename and initial directory already set.

Comment: as my knowledge, you are passing parameters to form class . but SaveFileDialog is the class which  specify options for saving file. SaveFileDialog is a class which Provides a mechanism to enable user to specify options for saving file. is this code works?

Comment: There is a savefiledialog in the form, which I am now finding out is probably the wrong way to go.  Would ditching the form and creating savefiledialog directly be the correct thing to do?

Comment: do you mean using saveFileDialog without Form? me, my self don't recommend that, but you know your application more than any body else, so it's your decision. take a look at correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620436/is-it-possible-to-have-savefiledialog-in-windows-console-applications

Comment: See my other question here.  The persons answer is confusing me and making it seem like I should remove the form as according to him it will be blank since all it has is a saveFileDialog.  Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283875/visual-studio-designer-bottom-pane#30283893

Comment: as you described in that question,as others, i think you don't need form too.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try without the form.  Since I'm a bit hung up on what ShowDialog() will actually do when called on the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need an event handler to do that. for example add a button. In button_Click method, call the ShowDialog method on the saveFileDialog instance. this example in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) shows an example that saves file with text extension.

EDIT

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "DefaultName.txt";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";


    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
            streamWriter.Write("some text");

    }
}
```

here i placed my saveFileDialog in my form, but I set default name and .... in that event handler

Comment: I have a button_Click method that could do that.  But my saveFileDialog is on a form, so  I'm having trouble passing the correct variables to the form and then the saveFileDialog.  Should I just create a saveFileDialog without a form?

Comment: it's ok you placed your saveFileDialog in your form, but you need event handler to reach its properties, check my edited answer

Comment: I see but where do I instantiate the form?  And how can I pass vartiables to saveFileDialog from outside the form?  Only way I can see to do it is to pass them to constructor of the form.  But in order to set those properties you would have to pass them to initializecomponent which you aren't supposed to edit.  So I don't see how to do it.

Comment: @shenk in order to do this, yes you should instantiate your form in your application like this:  var frm = new Form1(); frm.ShowDialog(); when user clicks on button a save As form opens which user can set the name and path for saving file.

Comment: I added the filename and path to form constructor, and then in form load handler I added the savefileDialog filename and path properties.  That should do it yes?  As for the results and stream writer, I am using the outlook mailitem save as method for saving.  My question is, doesn't savefileDialog save it for you, do you really need to use streamwriter and such? See my edit

Comment: no, this stream writer is only an example in order to write some text in file.

Comment: In the if statement you use the stream writer as an example as you said.  Does save file dialog save the file on it's own or do I need to write that logic myself inside the saveFileDialog_FileOK handler?

Comment: @shenk there is no need to write code to save. it saves on its own.