# Visual Studio Designer Bottom Pane

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-designer

What does it mean in the designer when you add something like saveFileDialog to a form, and it appears in the bottom pane at the bottom of the designer window rather than inside the form like a button would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When something like a SerialPort or SaveFileDialog appears at the bottom the designer, it just means that component is not a physical thing that gets drawn on the form/window.  To avoid confusion, it is displayed outside of the window.  You can click on it to see and change its properties, but it will not get drawn on the window the same way a button would.

Comment: I see, so what if I add it to a form?  Will it draw the form blank and the save dialog separately? Or just the save dialog?  Why add a save dialog to a form if it doesn't display within it?

Comment: Going to accept answer, but need some answers first. Thank you

Comment: The form will be blank if you have not added buttons or things like that to it.  The SaveFileDialog will not be displayed by default; you have to call ShowDialog to show it.  Usually you will do that in response to some user action such as clicking "Save" in a menu.

Comment: Well I have added a button to the ribbon which I want to display a custom save dialog with filename and initialdirectory already set.  So you are saying that it will display a blank form AND a save dialog?  To fix this what do I do?  Remove the form and just create a save file dialog myself?

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking about blank forms.  You should have things on your form in general; they should not be blank.  You should not make your own form and try to turn it into a SaveFileDialog, you should add the SaveFileDialog to a form that already exists where the user needs to be able to save something.

Comment: All I have is the saveFileDialog.  I just wanted a custom saveFileDialog as I said before.  I added it to the form.  But I'm asking will this work or will two dialogs pop up?  A blank one and a save dialog?

Comment: Your entire app has no buttons, menus, lists, or anything?  Then you should probably be using a different template; just create and show the SaveFileDialog in main() and don't ever display a main window.

Comment: It's a little different, there are buttons on other forms that are drawn at certain points throughout the application.  But my quesiton is about this form in particular.  BTW, this is an outlook addin not a WPF application or anything.  So basically remove the form and just create a savefiledialog directly and use that?

Comment: To clarify, the way I have it now.  Two windows would be drawn.  A blank form and a saveFileDialog?  And the fix would be remove the form and crate the saveFileDialog within my program where I currently create the form?

Comment: Sorry, this is getting far off topic.

Comment: Yes it is, somehwhat.  But my last question is related.  You are telling me items in bottom pane are drawn outside the form.  What is even the point of being able to add them to a form then?  Why would you even want a form and a saveFileDialog to open at the same time?  I'm just trying to understand whether I should get rid of the form and create a saveFileDialog directly or not based on your answer.

Comment: Imagine developing a text editor.  The form has the text you are editing, and a "Save" button.  When you click Save, you want that window to still be visible but you also want to show a SaveFileDialog.

Comment: I'm not though, it's an outlook addin.  You click a button and a save file dialog opens with initialdirectory and filename preset for you.  You are telling me that having the dialog inside a form is wrong.  Other people say it's right.  I am getting confused. I'm not sure whether to remove the form and create saveFileDialog in the click handler instead of creating the form.

Comment: Sounds like you should create the SaveFileDialog directly instead of using a form.  But this is extremely off topic.