# Save File Dialog in Outlook VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to create a save file dialog that opens when you press a custom ribbon button and has the filename and initialdirectory properties set to certain values.  Right now I create that dialog within a form.  In the designer it shows in the bottom pane as it is not an item that is drawn directly on the form, or so I've been told in this quesiton: [Visual Studio Designer Bottom Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283875/visual-studio-designer-bottom-pane)

My question is this: Should I remove the form and create the saveFileDialog on its own?  Or if I keep the form, when I call form.ShowDialog() will it show the saveFileDialog I added with the designer?  Or do I need to call saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()?  (Which I can't do outside of the class).  I'm not sure what the correct way to implement a custom saveFileDialog is.  I was once told to create a form, and now it seems like I should not use a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you absolutely need to use a save dialog via a form;

In your ribbon code add this:

On top

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Then this function

```
/// <summary>
/// Return selected file from winform save dialog
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fn">The filename</param>
/// <param name="id">The initial directory</param>
/// <returns>Specified filename</returns>
private string SaveFileTo(string id, string fn)
{
    SaveFileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog();
    //fd.OverwritePrompt = false;
    fd.AddExtension = true;
    fd.ValidateNames = true;
    fd.FileName = fn;
    fd.InitialDirectory = id;
    //fd.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf|Other ext like music|*.mp3;*.wma|All File|*.*";
    fd.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf";
    if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        return fd.FileName;
    return "";
}
```

And, in the method of your ribbon button

```
string s = SaveFileTo(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents", "MyAtt");
//Do something with s
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

As you can see in the function, two lines are commented, you can uncomment them and or modify them like you want your app to work

Comment: I don't get your examples point with s =  or the id, but it does work

Comment: After `string s = SaveFileTo(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents", "MyAtt");` , if you just click `Save` you will get `s = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyAtt.pdf"` as returned filename ; id is Initial Directory ; if you talk about the `@`, I used it to escape the `\\`